# Cannot locate resource 'themes/style/master.xaml'

Tags: wpf, path

Here is my Solution explorer:

[image]

I want to make this:

```
ResourceDictionary dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
dictionary.Source = new Uri("../Themes/Generic.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary());
```

in the constructor of PageWithoutMaster.

I get error: Cannot locate resource 'themes/style/master.xaml'

What am I doing wrong? Why is it adding the style folder in the path?

Comment: did you try with absolute URI: `pack://application:,,,/projectname;component/Themes/Generic.xaml`?

Comment: dictionary.Source= new Uri("Themes/Generic.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

Comment: @HeenaPatil The same error.

Comment: @dkozi It doesn't work :(

Comment: @petko_stankoski did you replace `projectname` with your real assembly name?

Comment: themes/style/master.xaml error .....where is theme folder and where is style folder inside it ?

Comment: @dkozl Yes, I did this: pack://application:,,,/companyName.UI;component/Themes/Generic.xaml", UriKind.Absolute
The name of the project is companyName.UI

Comment: @HeenaPatil You can see that from the picture above.

Comment: theme folder doesn't have any subfolder viz "Style"

Comment: @HeenaPatil I know that. That's what my problem is. There is no such path

Comment: @petko_stankoski make sure that's really your assembly name. It must be set to whatever is in _properties of assembly -> Application -> Assembly Name_ field

Comment: @dkozl I tried this: pack://application:,,,/assemblyname;component/Themes/Generic.xaml
And it doesnt work

Comment: and is `assemblyname` the name of assembly as defined in properties of that assembly?

Comment: @dkozl Yes. I right clicked on the project->Properties-.Application->Asembly name. That's the one

Comment: I'm guessing that you merge _master.xaml_ in _Generic.xaml_. Did you try setting path to _master.xaml_, where you reference it, in the same way `/assemblyname;component/Style/master.xaml`?

Answer (score 0):

As [dkozl pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526975/cannot-locate-resource-themes-style-master-xaml#comment37982500_24526975), you can fix this by using a [**Pack URI**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#using-pack-uris-in-markup) and including the assembly name in your path

Assuming your resource file looks something like this:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4.Themes">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Style/Master.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Get your assembly name from your project properties:

[image]

Then update to this value instead:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary Source="WpfApp4;component/Style/Master.xaml" />
```